# How to stop NetworkManager on KDE from disabling flaky Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: networkmanager, plasma

Basically as the title - since changing from GNOME to KDE (Plasma 6) on NixOS it keeps disabling my Wi-Fi connection permanently when it is flaky. I don't want that ever to happen, because I always want the computer to keep trying to reconnect forever. How do I achieve that? Re-enabling the connection manually is not an option when I need to connect to this machine from elsewhere on the regular.